# Mobile Dart workflows in Chrome Dev Editor

Tags: mobile, dart, google-chrome-app

Maybe you'll have some ideas.

So, are there any articles / tutorial / anything regarding the topic of [Mobile Dart workflows in Chrome Dev Editor](https://www.google.com/events/io/schedule/session/410cedbc-d6e1-e311-b297-00155d5066d7) Develop Sandbox from Google IO 2014?

I especially interested on these topics, multi-screen and mobile workflows, and  debugging apps directly on phones and tablets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workflows for deploying dart apps (chrome app and web apps) to mobile won't land until the next release - M14 - on or around the end of July. You can track this bug for the M14 release: https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/issues/2778.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Getting Started](https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/blob/master/doc/GettingStarted.md#chrome-app-workflow-including-mobile) on developing mobile apps in Chrome Dev Editor.

Comment: Just an FYI that the recommended "To-Do" app fails to run due to missing manifest items.